Can I recover a commit to a detached head after I've returned to main
I am using Github Desktop. I have a repository containing a unity project. Within that repository I have a submodule that containes a bunch of unity things that I use in every project.
I commited and pushed the changes to the submodule and then realised the submodule was on a detached head.
I switched back to the main branch but the changes i pushed to the detached head are not there.
Can i recover the changes i pushed to the detached head?
I tried git reflog. I see the detached head as well as the commit I made to it. But I dont know what to do from there.
git reflog result
"Lots for things" Is the commit I made to the detached head

Git restore last detached HEAD is worth a  read. Basically you create a branch at the commit and then you can do all the things you normally would, like merge it back to the main branch.
